# How do you change require_grad to false for each parameters in your model in pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

My code is below which I thought would do what I want but the output shows require_grad didn't change to false.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

encoder = nn.Sequential( nn.Conv2d(1, 4, 1), nn.Sigmoid())

for params in encoder.parameters():

    params.require_grad = False
    print(params.requires_grad) # prints two True statements?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not using `with torch.no_grad():`?

Comment: my goal is to use/train part of the network so I would like to freeze 80% of the layers first. After a certain epoch, I could then unlock more layers. I guess I can use the torch.no_grad() wrapper and unlock the convolutions 1 by 1 by setting require_grad = True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a typo :) Simply add an s at the end of grad in     `params.require_grad = False`

Change this to `params.requires_grad = False` (note the added s)

Typos can be hard to catch sometimes ;)

Comment: Thank you plus the fact that params.require_grad = False gives back no error because you assigned a new attribute which made it even harder to debug.